# Proper definition use in Stoke's theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, greens-theorem

Let the curve C be a piecewise smooth and simple closed curve enclosing a region, D.

Some sources asserts Stoke's theorem to be:

$$\oint_{C} F.dr = \iint_{R}\nabla \times FdS$$

Whereas, some claims it to be

$$\oint_{C} F.dr = \iint_{R}\nabla \times F.n.dS$$

Could someone clear the air as to which of the above definition used is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have rolled back edits of this question to the almost original state. I have done this on purpose because the slight notational confusion of the early versions of this question is the key point, which is addressed in the answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the first of the statements, the surface integral is written as $$\iint_R \nabla\times \vec F \cdot d\vec S$$ where I have added overarrows to clarify vector quantities. In particular, $d\vec S$ means integrating over the surface in the direction of the unit normal.

In the second statement the surface integral is written as

$$\iint_R \nabla\times\vec F \cdot \hat n \ dS$$

where $\hat n$ is the unit normal and the integral now is over the surface treated as a 'scalar'. Loosely speaking, $d\vec S = \hat n \, dS$.

In other words, the two statements properly understood are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you.
That was helpful.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Why is this down voted? I thought Simon's post was insightful and clear.